# Vector Search in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, vectorization, vector-search

I need to create a Vector database in AWS. I was using Pinecone in my POC, but for safety reasons the company need something inside AWS. I saw some people recommending to use OpenSearch, but I read in a blog that OpenSearch don't really do Vector Search

> Documented in
> https://www.elastic.co/blog/text-similarity-search-with-vectors-in-elasticsearch
> the approach to vector search has exactly the same limitation as what
> we observed with Solr: it will retrieve all documents that match the
> search criteria (keyword query along with filters on document
> attributes), and score all of them with the vector similarity of
> choice (cosine distance, dot-product or L1/L2 norms). That is, vector
> similarity will not be used during retrieval (first and expensive
> step): it will instead be used during document scoring (second step).
> Therefore, since you can’t know in advance, how many documents to
> fetch to surface most semantically relevant, the mathematical idea of
> vector search is not really applied.

Does any one know any alternative, or is OpenSearch the best we can do in AWS? I read some people talking about using DynamoDB too, but I didn't fully understand how it work. If any one have any ideas or suggestions I would really appreciate.

Souce: https://towardsdatascience.com/speeding-up-bert-search-in-elasticsearch-750f1f34f455

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Amazon OpenSearch](https://aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/) has a vector based search plugin called as `kNN` and has experimental features to allow users to perform semantic search.

Reference: [K-NN](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/search-plugins/knn/index/) 
[AWS K-NN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/knn.html) 
[Semantic Search feature](https://opensearch.org/blog/opensearch-2-4-is-available-today/#apply-semantic-search-and-sharpen-results-with-experimental-tools)

Comment: Yes, Try using this package which has simplified the vector search on OpenSearch:
https://github.com/mjdileep/Opencone

Answer (score 3):

try some newer ones like qdrant, weaviate, milvus . A lot easier to use and less resource hungry than opensearch.

Answer (score 0):

Pls take a look at https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/vector-search/cql.html You can get super fast and high recall ANN out of Astra Vector powered by Apache Cassandra. Here is a sample query

```
SELECT * FROM vsearch.products 
ORDER BY item_vector ANN OF [0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.35, 0.55]
LIMIT 1;
```